Tapo L530E not reconized in my custom smart home skill
I'm building a smart home skill to control a smart bulb based on data fetched from a Dynamodb table. I'm good so far with the data fetch part, but now I'm trying to convert the data from the database into different actions on the smart bulb, such as turning it on, turning it off, changing brightness, changing color, etc.
I bought a Tapo L530E smart light bulb. I followed the procedure for registering it on the Tapo app. After linking the Tapo app with the Alexa app (or enabling the Tapo skill on the Alexa app), the device was successfully discovered and showed up in my devices list.
The problem is that I cannot "recognize" the smart bulb device within my custom skill. When checking the CloudWatch log, no Discovery request was sent to the skill. If I delete the Tapo bulb from my devices list and ask Alexa to discover new devices, I get two new devices, the Tapo bulb and a Sample Light virtual device. After checking again on CloudWatch, I can only see one Discovery request corresponding to the Sample Light.
I followed the tutorial from Amazon to build my skill. The lambda function is just as shown in the tutorial, with only a few tweaks. This is python, by the way.
import json
import math
import random
import uuid
import logging
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timezone

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(request, context):

    # Dump the request for logging - check the CloudWatch logs.
    print('lambda_handler request  -----')
    print(json.dumps(request))


    if context is not None:
        print('lambda_handler context  -----')
        print(context)

    # Validate the request is an Alexa smart home directive.
    if 'directive' not in request:
        alexa_response = AlexaResponse(
            name='ErrorResponse',
            payload={'type': 'INVALID_DIRECTIVE',
                     'message': 'Missing key: directive, Is the request a valid Alexa Directive?'})
        return send_response(alexa_response.get())

    # Check the payload version.
    payload_version = request['directive']['header']['payloadVersion']
    if payload_version != '3':
        alexa_response = AlexaResponse(
            name='ErrorResponse',
            payload={'type': 'INTERNAL_ERROR',
                     'message': 'This skill only supports Smart Home API version 3'})
        return send_response(alexa_response.get())

    # Crack open the request to see the request.
    name = request['directive']['header']['name']
    namespace = request['directive']['header']['namespace']
    #endpointID = request['directive']['header']['endpoint_id']

    # Handle the incoming request from Alexa based on the namespace.
    if namespace == 'Alexa.Authorization':
        if name == 'AcceptGrant':
            # Note: This example code accepts any grant request.
            # In your implementation, invoke Login With Amazon with the grant code to get access and refresh tokens.
            grant_code = request['directive']['payload']['grant']['code']
            grantee_token = request['directive']['payload']['grantee']['token']
            auth_response = AlexaResponse(namespace='Alexa.Authorization', name='AcceptGrant.Response')
            return send_response(auth_response.get())

    if namespace == 'Alexa.Discovery':
        if name == 'Discover':
            # The request to discover the devices the skill controls.
            discovery_response = AlexaResponse(namespace='Alexa.Discovery', name='Discover.Response')
            # Create the response and add the light bulb capabilities.
            capability_alexa = discovery_response.create_payload_endpoint_capability()
            capability_alexa_powercontroller = discovery_response.create_payload_endpoint_capability(
                interface='Alexa.PowerController',
                supported=[{'name': 'powerState'}])
            capability_alexa_colorcontroller = discovery_response.create_payload_endpoint_capability(
                interface='Alexa.ColorController',
                supported=[{'name': 'color'}])
            capability_alexa_brightcontroller = discovery_response.create_payload_endpoint_capability(
                interface='Alexa.BrightnessController',
                supported=[{'name': 'brightness'}])
            capability_alexa_endpointhealth = discovery_response.create_payload_endpoint_capability(
                interface='Alexa.EndpointHealth',
                supported=[{'name': 'connectivity'}])
            discovery_response.add_payload_endpoint(
                #friendly_name='Sample Light Bulb',
                #endpoint_id='endpointID',
                capabilities=[capability_alexa, capability_alexa_endpointhealth, capability_alexa_powercontroller,capability_alexa_colorcontroller,capability_alexa_brightcontroller])
            return send_response(discovery_response.get())

    if namespace == 'Alexa.PowerController':
        # The directive to TurnOff or TurnOn the light bulb.
        # Note: This example code always returns a success response.
        endpoint_id = request['directive']['endpoint']['endpointId']
        power_state_value = 'OFF' if name == 'TurnOff' else 'ON'
        correlation_token = request['directive']['header']['correlationToken']

        # Check for an error when setting the state.
        device_set = update_device_state(endpoint_id=endpoint_id, state='powerState', value=power_state_value)
        if not device_set:
            return AlexaResponse(
                name='ErrorResponse',
                payload={'type': 'ENDPOINT_UNREACHABLE', 'message': 'Unable to reach endpoint database.'}).get()

        directive_response = AlexaResponse(correlation_token=correlation_token)
        directive_response.add_context_property(namespace='Alexa.PowerController', name='powerState', value=power_state_value)
        return send_response(directive_response.get())

    


# Send the response
def send_response(response):
    print('lambda_handler response -----')
    print(json.dumps(response))
    return response

# Make the call to your device cloud for control
def update_device_state(endpoint_id, state, value):
    attribute_key = state + 'Value'
    # result = stubControlFunctionToYourCloud(endpointId, token, request);
    return True
    

# Datetime format for timeOfSample is ISO 8601, `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`.
def get_utc_timestamp(seconds=None):
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()

class AlexaResponse:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.context_properties = []
        self.payload_endpoints = []

        # Set up the response structure.
        self.context = {}
        self.event = {
            'header': {
                'namespace': kwargs.get('namespace', 'Alexa'),
                'name': kwargs.get('name', 'Response'),
                'messageId': str(uuid.uuid4()),
                'payloadVersion': kwargs.get('payload_version', '3')
            },
            'endpoint': {
                "scope": {
                    "type": "BearerToken",
                    "token": kwargs.get('token', 'INVALID')
                },
                "endpointId": kwargs.get('endpoint_id', 'INVALID')
            },
            'payload': kwargs.get('payload', {})
        }

        if 'correlation_token' in kwargs:
            self.event['header']['correlation_token'] = kwargs.get('correlation_token', 'INVALID')

        if 'cookie' in kwargs:
            self.event['endpoint']['cookie'] = kwargs.get('cookie', '{}')

        # No endpoint property in an AcceptGrant or Discover request.
        if self.event['header']['name'] == 'AcceptGrant.Response' or self.event['header']['name'] == 'Discover.Response':
            self.event.pop('endpoint')

    def add_context_property(self, **kwargs):
        self.context_properties.append(self.create_context_property(**kwargs))
        self.context_properties.append(self.create_context_property())


    def add_cookie(self, key, value):

        if "cookies" in self is None:
            self.cookies = {}

        self.cookies[key] = value

    def add_payload_endpoint(self, **kwargs):
        self.payload_endpoints.append(self.create_payload_endpoint(**kwargs))


    def create_context_property(self, **kwargs):
        return {
            'namespace': kwargs.get('namespace', 'Alexa.EndpointHealth'),
            'name': kwargs.get('name', 'connectivity'),
            'value': kwargs.get('value', {'value': 'OK'}),
            'timeOfSample': get_utc_timestamp(),
            'uncertaintyInMilliseconds': kwargs.get('uncertainty_in_milliseconds', 0)
        }

    def create_payload_endpoint(self, **kwargs):
        # Return the proper structure expected for the endpoint.
        # All discovery responses must include the additionAttributes
        additionalAttributes = {
            'manufacturer': kwargs.get('manufacturer', 'Sample Manufacturer'),
            'model': kwargs.get('model_name', 'Sample Model'),
            'serialNumber': kwargs.get('serial_number', 'U11112233456'),
            'firmwareVersion': kwargs.get('firmware_version', '1.24.2546'),
            'softwareVersion': kwargs.get('software_version', '1.036'),
            'customIdentifier': kwargs.get('custom_identifier', 'Sample custom ID')
        }

        endpoint = {
            'capabilities': kwargs.get('capabilities', []),
            'description': kwargs.get('description'),
            'displayCategories': kwargs.get('display_categories', ['LIGHT']),
            'endpointId': kwargs.get('endpoint_id', 'endpoint_' + "%0.6d" % random.randint(0, 999999)),
            'friendlyName': kwargs.get('friendly_name', 'Sample light'),
            'manufacturerName': kwargs.get('manufacturer_name', 'Sample Manufacturer')
        }

        endpoint['additionalAttributes'] = kwargs.get('additionalAttributes', additionalAttributes)
        if 'cookie' in kwargs:
            endpoint['cookie'] = kwargs.get('cookie', {})

        return endpoint

    def create_payload_endpoint_capability(self, **kwargs):
        # All discovery responses must include the Alexa interface
        capability = {
            'type': kwargs.get('type', 'AlexaInterface'),
            'interface': kwargs.get('interface', 'Alexa'),
            'version': kwargs.get('version', '3')
        }
        supported = kwargs.get('supported', None)
        if supported:
            capability['properties'] = {}
            capability['properties']['supported'] = supported
            capability['properties']['proactivelyReported'] = kwargs.get('proactively_reported', False)
            capability['properties']['retrievable'] = kwargs.get('retrievable', False)
        return capability

    def get(self, remove_empty=True):

        response = {
            'context': self.context,
            'event': self.event
        }

        if len(self.context_properties) > 0:
            response['context']['properties'] = self.context_properties

        if len(self.payload_endpoints) > 0:
            response['event']['payload']['endpoints'] = self.payload_endpoints

        if remove_empty:
            if len(response['context']) < 1:
                response.pop('context')

        return response

    def set_payload(self, payload):
        self.event['payload'] = payload

    def set_payload_endpoint(self, payload_endpoints):
        self.payload_endpoints = payload_endpoints

    def set_payload_endpoints(self, payload_endpoints):
        if 'endpoints' not in self.event['payload']:
            self.event['payload']['endpoints'] = []

        self.event['payload']['endpoints'] = payload_endpoints

Bottom line, how can my custom skill discover the Tapo L530E so it can control it?
I'm new to AWS and Smart Home Skills, so I may be missing a basic concept in this process.
